# outputted HTML file linking back to the java program

Tags: java, html

In my Java program, I have to output an HTML file with buttons such as sending or displaying specific emails, which is saved in this java program (will run on a server). How do I link this HTML file so that when the button is clicked, it actually calls a method in the java program (such as the send email method) and affects some fields, such as the list that stores the emails? If there is not a way to do this, how can I achieve what I want to do? Thank you.

This is the code I have for GUI, but I do not want GUI. I want to turn all these codes into an outputted HTML file. So basically, in place of these codes, I need to output an HTML file that does exactly the same thing as this GUI does. The reason I need to output a webpage is that when the program is launched onto the server, GUI is not that handy. I believe the program will always be running and in the main I have a timeTask that runs this routine once a day.

```
public void createEmailPanel(String name, final Email email) {
    final JPanel emailPanel = new JPanel();
    emailPanel.setLayout(null);
    emailPanel.setSize(900, 50);
    panel.add(emailPanel);

    String emails = "";
    for(String a : email.getList()) {
        emails = emails + a + " ";
    }

    JLabel labelName = new JLabel(emails);
    labelName.setLocation(0, 0);
    labelName.setSize(700, 30);
    emailPanel.add(labelName);

    JButton display = new JButton("Display Email");
    display.setLocation(0, 50);
    display.setSize(200, 30);
    display.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JEditorPane HtmlPane= new JEditorPane();
            boolean fail = false;
            try {
                File temp = File.createTempFile("temp", ".html");
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
                out.write(email.getBody());
                out.close();

                HtmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
                HtmlPane.setEditable(false);
                try {
                    HtmlPane.setPage(temp.toURI().toURL());
                } catch (MalformedURLException a) {
                    fail = true;
                    JPanel p = new JPanel();
                    p.setSize(500, 200);
                    p.setLayout(null);

                    JLabel labelName = new JLabel("Error displaying emails");
                    labelName.setLocation(0, 0);
                    labelName.setSize(700, 30);
                    p.add(labelName);

                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setSize(500, 200);
                    f.add(p);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(HtmlPane);
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setSize(800, 500);
                f.add(jsp);
                f.setVisible(true);
                temp.delete();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                if(fail) {
                    JPanel p = new JPanel();
                    p.setSize(500, 200);
                    p.setLayout(null);

                    JLabel labelName = new JLabel("Error displaying emails");
                    labelName.setLocation(0, 0);
                    labelName.setSize(700, 30);
                    p.add(labelName);

                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setSize(500, 200);
                    f.add(p);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }

        }
    });
    emailPanel.add(display);


    JButton sendRecipient = new JButton("Send Email to Recipients");
    sendRecipient.setLocation(440, 50);
    sendRecipient.setSize(200, 30);
    sendRecipient.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            email.sendEmailToRecipients();
            queue.remove(email);
            panel.remove(emailPanel);
            JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            pane.setSize(900, 50);
            panel.add(pane);
            JLabel labe = new JLabel("Email sent to recipients.");
            labe.setSize(900, 50);
            labe.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
            pane.add(labe);
            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });
    emailPanel.add(sendRecipient);
```

email is an Email object which has a method of sendEmailRecipient that uses JavaMail. Also, the body of the email is an HTML as well, maybe irrelevant here.

Comment: Post your code so other users can help you.

Comment: Is your program running inside some J2EE Container?

Comment: I guess you will have to use something like Servlets, JSP or JSF and a J2EE container like Tomcat. But this would be a completely different approach compared with your current implementation. To be able to help we need much more information about your system and architecture.

Comment: @mschenk74 I was just told it will be launched to a server. I am not familiar with the system and architecture. For now, I just need to achieve this on my computer.

Comment: You need to define how the generated HTML will be displayed and how the user interaction reaches your code.

Comment: @mschenk74 That is the part I don't know how to do. I don't know how the generated HTML file can access my code. I just need to be able to open the HTML file in a browser and want it to work just as GUI does.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to look at tutorials and whitepapers of Servlets, JSPs JSF and similar frameworks to decide which one fits best with your requirements. There is no simple solution that can be explained here in a few sentences.